# Какую встроенную в .NET технологию использовать для связи программ?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Имеются около 20 виртуальных машин с Windows XP, на них установлена программа (написана мной) которой необходимо управлять. То есть сейчас стартую разработку менеджера по удаленному контролю работой этих программ. Подскажите какую технологию проще использовать для обмена данными между этими программами по одноранговой сети доступную из коробки в .NET?

Comment: я бы предложил REST.

Comment: Мне кажется, WCF как раз для этого.

Comment: SignalR набирает популярность, но руками я его еще не пробовал, поэтому пока придерживаюсь WCF